# Flutter Create String from a future<File> in order to inspect last 3 characters of filename

Tags: flutter

I am using image_picker which returns a string of a path, it is a future, so when I get the future I want to be able to check the last 3 characters to what file type it is image or movie.  It seems everything I try is either can't set string to Future or same for int when I am trying a substring. The code I am showing is the container for the future builder for the return of the selected file. Let me know if you want to see anything else.

```
new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
          child: new FutureBuilder<File>(
              future: _imageFile,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  //return new Image.file(snapshot.data);
                  myimagefile = snapshot.data;
                  return new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        width: 150.0,
                        child: new Image.file(snapshot.data),
                      ),
                      new FlatButton(
                          onPressed: _doClear, child: new Text('Clear Image'))
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Text('');
                }
              })
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [path](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path) package makes it easy to get the extension

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path; 

var file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
var ext = path.extension(file.path);
```

`await` only works in a function/method marked as `async`.
I would need to see the code where and how you call the image picker for more concrete example code.

Comment: Any ideas on how to show a video similar to how Image.file works from images?  I need to show the user the video is there, but have it play in default platform video player.

Comment: Sorry, don't know yet, but I'll need that in the next weeks myelf.